# Scala - merging two JSON files

Tags: json, scala

I am trying to use the JSON library in `scala.util.parsing.json` to parse JSON files. I am able to read and parse a JSON file, but how do I combine two JSON files together? (the overlapping values in the second file should over-write the first).

Answer (score 2):

For Scala it is recommended to use liftweb json library. Which is feature rich and more widely accepted JSON library than scala internal one.  Merge is available in liftweb json library,

http://olim7t.github.com/liftweb-2.0-release-sxr/net/liftweb/json/Merge.scala.html

Comment: Recommended by whom? *[citation needed]

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/927983/how-can-i-construct-and-parse-a-json-string-in-scala-lift and http://scala-programming-language.1934581.n4.nabble.com/Does-scala-util-parsing-json-JSON-worth-trying-td3234964.html