# Suggestions for Writing Map as JSON file in Scala

Tags: json, scala, dictionary

I have a simple single key-valued Map(K,V) **myDictionary** that is populated by my program and at the end I want to write it as JSON format string in a text file - as I would need parse them later.

I was using this code earlier,

```
Some(new PrintWriter(outputDir+"/myDictionary.json")).foreach{p => p.write(compact(render(decompose(myDictionary)))); p.close}
```

I found it to be slower as the input size increased. Later, I used this var out = new

```
var out = new PrintWriter(outputDir+"/myDictionary.json");
out.println(scala.util.parsing.json.JSONObject(myDictionary.toMap).toString())
```

This is proving to be bit faster.

I have run this for sample input and found that this is faster than my earlier approach. I assuming my input map size would reach at least **a million values( >1GB text file)** (K,V) hence I want to make sure that I follow the faster and memory efficient approach for Map serialization process.What are other approaches that you would recommend,that I can look into to optimize this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The JSON support in the standard Scala library is probably not the best choice. Unfortunately the situation with JSON libraries for Scala is a bit confusing, there are [many alternatives](https://wiki.scala-lang.org/display/SW/Tools+and+Libraries#ToolsandLibraries-JSON) (Lift JSON, Play JSON, Spray JSON, Twitter JSON, Argonaut, ...), basically one library for each day of the week... I suggest you have a look at these at least to see if any of them is easier to use and more performative.

---

Here is an example using Play JSON which I have chosen for particular reasons (being able to generate formats with macros):

```
object JsonTest extends App {
  import play.api.libs.json._

  type MyDict = Map[String, Int]

  implicit object MyDictFormat extends Format[MyDict] {
    def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[MyDict] = json match {
      case JsObject(fields) =>
        val b = Map.newBuilder[String, Int]
        fields.foreach {
          case (k, JsNumber(v)) => b += k -> v.toInt
          case other => return JsError(s"Not a (string, number) pair: $other")
        }
        JsSuccess(b.result())

      case _ => JsError(s"Not an object: $json")
    }

    def writes(m: MyDict): JsValue = {
      val fields: Seq[(String, JsValue)] = m.map {
        case (k, v) => k -> JsNumber(v)
      } (collection.breakOut)

      JsObject(fields)
    }
  }

  val m       = Map("hallo" -> 12, "gallo" -> 34)
  val serial  = Json.toJson(m)
  val text    = Json.stringify(serial)
  println(text)
  val back    = Json.fromJson[MyDict](serial)
  assert(back == JsSuccess(m), s"Failed: $back")
}
```

While you can construct and deconstruct `JsValues` directly, the main idea is to use a `Format[A]` where `A` is the type of your data structure. This puts more emphasis on type safety than the standard Scala-Library JSON. It looks more verbose, but in end I think it's the better approach.

There are utility methods `Json.toJson` and `Json.fromJson` which look for an implicit format of the type you want.

On the other hand, it does construct everything in-memory and it does duplicate your data structure (because for each entry in your map you will have another tuple `(String, JsValue)`), so this isn't necessarily the most memory efficient solution, given that you are operating in the GB magnitude...

---

Jerkson is a Scala wrapper for the Java JSON library Jackson. The latter [apparently has the feature to stream data](http://bcomposes.wordpress.com/2012/05/12/processing-json-in-scala-with-jerkson/). I found [this project](https://github.com/ymasory/jerkson-streaming) which says it adds streaming support. Play JSON in turn is based on Jerkson, so perhaps you can even figure out how to stream your object with that. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444380/is-there-a-streaming-api-for-json).

Comment: Exactly my problem. Too many choices and I couldn't find a proper article comparing them except this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8054018/json-library-for-scala . Googling didn't help me either.

Comment: I have added an example for Play JSON. I vaguely remember there is also a possibility with one of these libraries to use streaming I/O, which would probably avoid having to use twice as much memory as your input data structure...

Comment: If memory is an issue, perhaps you could just split your big map into several chucks which are encoded as individual JSON objects...

Comment: Thanks for the detailed updates. Memory is not an issue. Just that, while writing it as file and reading back takes a long time. Is there any way to reduce the overhead ?

Comment: No, performance will at best be linear with the size of your map. If it blocks your application, do I/O in a dedicated thread or future... Otherwise you could use a different mechanism, like a Key-Value store (I have good experience with BerkeleyDB JE). There is also [this project](https://github.com/emchristiansen/PersistentMap), not sure how mature it is.