# How to convert scala list to list of list

Tags: scala

Below in my scala list

```
List((1409497202065,0.533), (1411804719,0.533), (1411804735,0.533), (1411811091,0.0))
```

Now how should I convert above list to get following output

```
List(List(1409497202065,0.533),List(1411804719,0.533), List(1411804735,0.533), List(1411811091,0.0))
```

Comment: `myList.map(List(_))` ?

Comment: it create list as below List(List((1409497202065,0.533)), List((1411804719,0.533)), List((1411804735,0.533)), List((1411811091,0.0)))

Comment: Hi Neu it work fine but one problem that when I should parse above list  to json in play framework "No Json serializer found for type List[List[(Long, Float)]]" and I converted as  below Json.toJson(convert) I think for Long value it may not parse, how should it parse in json

Comment: I think you should edit your question, I don't see no json functionality nor I would know how to answer that anyway, as it stands it's unclear what you're asking.

Comment: maybe you should rename it to "How to convert scala list of tuple to list of list"

Comment: Your question is incomplete and incorrect. What JSON library are you using? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8054018/json-library-for-scala

Answer (score 2):

Given that `lst` is the aforementioned list, you could map it directly like this:

```
lst.map {
  case (a, b) => List(a, b)
  case _ => Nil // just in case you got some data that doesn't fit
}
```

this will produce a `List[List[Double]]` that looks like the following:

```
List(List(1409497202065.0,0.533),List(1411804719.0,0.533), List(1411804735.0,0.533), List(1411811091.0,0.0))
```

The beauty of the system above, is that it's infinitely expandable; since it's always possible to add more cases to the `match` block

ps: the first number in your list is too large to be an integer, this could be fixed by using `String`s `BigInt`s, `Long`s or even `Double`s

Comment: I think "just in case" case is redundant because `lst` is of type `List[(Double, Double)]`, so it just can't contain anything which is not pair of doubles. Then it is possible to write this as a one-liner :)

Comment: @VladimirMatveev I like to cover my bases; and what it contains is actually `(Long, Double)` as the first number doesn't contain any decimal points

Comment: @VladimirMatveev it does only because I added it in to have them both be doubles; if you look at the original post you'll see the lack of a decimal point

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
myList.map(_.productIterator.toList) 

scala> val myList = List((14,0.533), (14118,0.533), (1735,0.533), (1411,0.0))
myList: List[(Int, Double)] = List((14,0.533), (14118,0.533), (1735,0.533), (1411,0.0))

scala> myList.map(_.productIterator.toList)
res22: List[List[Any]] = List(List(14, 0.533), List(14118, 0.533), List(1735, 0.533),     List(1411, 0.0))
```

`productIterator.toList` converts a tuple to a `List`, but changes the type to `Any`, so if you want this to be serializable in JSON you have to:

```
myList.map(_.productIterator.map(_.toString).toList)
```

You may want a *heterogeneous list* from the [Shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) library if the types in your tuple don't conform

If you just want a single `String` inside the `List`:

```
myList.map(_.productIterator.mkString(","))
```

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity and readability, consider this for comprehension for a given list `a` of duples,

```
for ( (x,y) <- a ) yield List(x,y)
```

This works also for (possibly) empty lists of duples.