# Scala unpickle with missing field

Tags: scala, scala-pickling

How can I unpickle an object with a field that might miss (and use an null) in that case?

```
scala> case class Person(name:String=null,age:Int)
defined class Person
scala> import scala.pickling.Defaults._, scala.pickling.json._
scala> val p2 = JSONPickle("""{"age":2}""").unpickle[Person]
scala.pickling.PicklingException: No field 'name' when unpickling, tag Person, fields were Map(age -> 2.0)
```

I need this in order to unpickle a string came from browser that is also missing the type field, so I will not be able to use an Option/Some/None type.

Comment: @jsuereth recommands https://github.com/sbt/serialization . I will take a look.

Answer (score 1):

Just declare it having type `Option[String]`, like this:

```
case class Person(name: Option[String], age: Int)
```

`Option[T]` is the idiomatic Scala way of handling values which otherwise (e.g. in Java) could be `null`

Comment: Unfortunately this was not an option since the web browser will need to create the json for Person and knowing the pickling internal format might be a little to much to ask. I was hoping that a formatter to plain simple json exists.

Comment: If you browser just don't send `name` field it will be treated as `None`.

Comment: I tested with Option[String] and it seems that it still fails if the name is missing. Besides what string should come from browser to have a Some("name1") as name? The browser should send something like {
  "$type": "Person",
  "name": {
    "$type": "scala.Some[java.lang.String]",
    "x": "name1"
  },
  "age": 1
} which is not something too elegant/robust.

Comment: Absolutely not! You may just send  `{"$type": "Person", "name": "name1, "age": 1}` or `{"$type": "Person", "age": 1}` if name is not present.

Comment: Can you share the imports that you are using to parse that string? I used `import scala.pickling.Defaults._, scala.pickling.json._` and it fails with `scala> val p2 = JSONPickle("""{"$type": "Person", "name": "name1", "age": 1}""").unpickle[Person]
scala.MatchError: name1 (of class java.lang.String)`

Answer (score 1):

To my understanding, scala-pickling can not handle missing fields.

If we look at the output of how scala-pickle pickles `Option`:

```
Some(9).pickle
// JSONPickle({
//   "$type": "scala.Some[scala.Int]",
//   "x": 9
// })

case class TestA(x: Option[Int])
TestA(None).pickle
// JSONPickle({
//   "$type": "TestA",
//   "x": {
//     "$type": "scala.None.type"
//   }
// })
```

You could use a [json library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8054018/what-json-library-to-use-in-scala) instead of a serialization library.

Given your json and case class with an optional name:

```
case class Person(name:Option[String], age:Int)
val json =  """{"age":2}"""
```

With json4s:

```
import org.json4s._
import org.json4s.JsonDSL._
import org.json4s.native.JsonMethods._

parse(json).extract[Person]
// Person = Person(None,2)
```

With argonaut :

```
import argonaut._, Argonaut._

implicit def PersonCodecJson = 
  casecodec2(Person.apply, Person.unapply)("name", "age")

json.decodeOption[Person]
// Option[Person] = Some(Person(None,2))
```