# Which JSON library to use when storing case objects?

Tags: json, scala, json4s, akka-persistence

I need to serialize akka events to json. Based on 
"[What JSON library to use in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8054018/what-json-library-to-use-in-scala)" I tried several libraries. Since my serializer should know nothing of all my concrete events, the events consisting of case classes and case objects should be serialised using reflection. [json4s](https://github.com/json4s/json4s) seems to match my requirements best.

```
class Json4sEventAdapter(system: ExtendedActorSystem) extends EventAdapter {
  implicit val formats = Serialization.formats(FullTypeHints(List(classOf[Evt])))
  override def toJournal(event: Any): Any = event match {
case e: AnyRef =>
  write(e).getBytes(Charsets.UTF_8)}

override def fromJournal(event: Any, manifest: String): EventSeq = event match {
case e: Array[Byte] => {
      EventSeq.single(read[Evt](new String(e.map(_.toChar))))}}
```

The problem using json4s is, that no matter which implementation is used [Deserialization of objects produces different instances](https://github.com/json4s/json4s/issues/105). 
Since we heavily use pattern matching for the case object this breaks all our existing code.

So my question is: which JSON library could be used with scala and akka persistence when storing case objects?

Is there even one library that handles deserialization of case objects via reflection correctly? - or does anyone have a good workaround?

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment on Json4s, since I've never used it, but I do know that this is a non-issue in [play-json](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaJson). You would do something like:

```
import play.api.libs.json._

sealed trait MyEventBase
case object MyEvent extends MyEventBase

implicit val myEventBaseFormat: Format[MyEventBase] = Format(Reads.StringReads.collect(ValidationError("must be the string `MyEvent`") {
  case "MyEvent" => MyEvent
}, Writes.pure("MyEvent"))
```

In this case, the serialization is to a bare string, and so I piggyback on the built-in `StringReads` to assert that the item should be deserializable to a string, and then use `collect` to narrow that down to the specific string. But the basic idea is that you provide the specific value you want back from deserialization in your `Reads` instance. Here, it's the singleton `case object`. So, whenever you deserialize a `MyEventBase` resulting in a `MyEvent`, you'll definitely get that same instance back.

In the real world, `MyEventBase` probably has other subtypes, and so you structure your `Writes` instance to create some form of type tag for serialization that your `Reads` instance can key off of to deserialize to the proper subtype. Like, you might serialize to a JSON object instead of a bare string, and that object would have a `type` field that identifies the subtype. Or just use something like [Play JSON Extensions](http://play-json-extra.megl.io/playjsonext.html) to automatically synthesize a reasonable `Format` for your `sealed trait`.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend you to have a look at [Stamina](https://github.com/scalapenos/stamina). It's been implemented to solve most of the usual issues you will encounter with akka-persistence.

It provides a json serialiser (based on spray-json and shapeless) which supports versioning, auto-migrating at read time as well as a testkit to ensure all older versions of persistent events are still readable.