# Escape characters in a dynamic List

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I'll like to escape characters in a dynamic List used in creating a case class.

```
case class Profile(biography: String,
                  userid: String,
                  creationdate: String) extends Serializable

object Profile {

  val cs = this.getClass.getConstructors
  def createFromList(params: List[Any]) = params match {
    case List(biography: Any,
              userid: Any,
              creationdate: Any) => Profile(StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(biography.asInstanceOf[String]),
                                            StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(creationdate.asInstanceOf[String]),
                                            StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(userid.asInstanceOf[String]))
  }
}

JSON.parseFull("""{"biography":"An avid learner","userid":"165774c2-a0e7-4a24-8f79-0f52bf3e2cda", "creationdate":"2015-07-13T07:48:47.924Z"}""")
  .map(_.get.asInstanceOf[scala.collection.immutable.Map[String, Any]])
  .map { 
    m => Profile.createFromList(m.values.to[collection.immutable.List])
   } saveToCassandra("testks", "profiles", SomeColumns("biography", "userid", "creationdate"))
```

I get this error:

```
scala.MatchError: List(An avid learner, 165774c2-a0e7-4a24-8f79-0f52bf3e2cda, 2015-07-13T07:48:47.925Z) (of class scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon)
```

Any ideas please?

Comment: Try `.toList` instead of `.to[collection.immutable.List]`

Comment: Thanks but same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be simpler to use a different (external) JSON library than `scala.util.parsing.json` (which has been deprecated since Scala 2.11).

There are a [lot of good Scala Json libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8054018/what-json-library-to-use-in-scala/14442630#14442630), below an example using [json4s](https://github.com/json4s/json4s).

```
import org.json4s._
import org.json4s.native.JsonMethods._

case class Profile(biography: String, userid: String, creationdate: String)

val json = """{
|  "biography":"An avid learner",
|  "userid":"165774c2-a0e7-4a24-8f79-0f52bf3e2cda", 
|  "creationdate":"2015-07-13T07:48:47.924Z"
|}""".stripMargin

parse(json).extract[Profile]
// Profile(An avid learner,165774c2-a0e7-4a24-8f79-0f52bf3e2cda,2015-07-13T07:48:47.924Z)
```