# Convert Json string to map in scala

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I have a JSON string, say:

```
val json = JSONObject(Map("a" -> 1)).toString()
```

I want to convert this json to map again. I tried:

```
val map = json.toMap[String, Int]
```

This gives me the following error:

```
Error:(46, 25) Cannot prove that Char <:< (String, Int).
val map = json.toMap[String, Int]
                    ^
Error:(46, 25) not enough arguments for method toMap: (implicit ev: <:<[Char,(String, Int)])scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int].
Unspecified value parameter ev.
val map = json.toMap[String, Int]
                    ^
```

What is the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

```
val map = json.toMap.asInstanceOf[Map[String, Int]]
```

Comment: This causes me the same error as in the OP. Also, this answer needs a bit more context, why should it work, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Using `play-json` you can convert Json to Map using `validate`. Validate returns `JsResult` which can be `JsSuccess(data,path)` or `JsError(errors)`. Pattern match to get the map out of it.

If you are using `sbt project` then add `play-json` dependency to your project.

*build.sbt*

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq("com.typesafe.play" %% "play-json" % "2.54.")
```

**Scala REPL**

```
scala> import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.json._

scala> val map = Map("java" -> 1, "scala" -> 2)
map: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(java -> 1, scala -> 2)

scala> Json.toJson(map).validate[Map[String, Int]]
res3: play.api.libs.json.JsResult[Map[String,Int]] = JsSuccess(Map(java -> 1, scala -> 2),)

scala> val result = Json.toJson(map).validate[Map[String, Int]]
result: play.api.libs.json.JsResult[Map[String,Int]] = JsSuccess(Map(java -> 1, scala -> 2),)

scala> result match { case JsSuccess(data, _) => data case JsError(errors) => Unit}
res4: Object = Map(java -> 1, scala -> 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is a one-off then you could do something like this:

```
  val json = JSONObject(Map("a" -> 1)).toString() //> json  : String = {"a" : 1}

  val map = json.substring(1, json.length - 1).split(":").map(_.trim) match {
    case Array(s: String, i: String) => Map(s -> i.toInt)
  }                                               //> map  : scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map("a" -> 1)
```

However, if you are doing more with Json then you probably want to explore the use of a library since I think the support for Json in the standard library is limited. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8054018/what-json-library-to-use-in-scala?answertab=active#tab-top) for a good overview of available libraries.