# No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class Definition]

Tags: java, json, scala, jackson

I have written a Scala program using Jackson framework to read a Json file.  I'm getting the following error whenever executing Scala program.  Could anyone suggest how I can overcome this error.

Error

```
Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class Definition]: can not instantiate from JSON object (need to add/enable type information?)
 at [Source: {  "recordDefinitions": [    {      "recordDefinitionIdentifier": 2,      "recordTypeCode": "LT",      "recordTypePattern": "^.{14}LT.*$",      "minimumNumberOfAttributes": 19,      "expectedNumberOfAttributes": 19,      "recordLength": 117,      "attributes": [        {          "attributeIdentifier": 1,          "attributeName": "PROVIDER TYPE",          "attributeMaximumLength": 1,          "datatype": {            "datatypeName": "AN"          }        }      ]    }  ]}; line: 1, column: 4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:148)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromObjectUsingNonDefault(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1071)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:264)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:124)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3066)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2161)
    at Json_Parser_Jackson$.main(Json_Parser_Jackson.scala:33)
    at Json_Parser_Jackson.main(Json_Parser_Jackson.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

Program

```
import java.io.{File, StringWriter}

    import java.util

    import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.`type`.TypeReference
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule
    import org.apache.avro.ipc.specific.Person

    import scala.io.Source


    case class Definition(recordDefinitions: Seq[RecordDefinitionsClass])
    case class RecordDefinitionsClass(recordDefinitionIdentifier:Int,recordTypeCode: String,recordTypePattern:String,minimumNumberOfAttributes: Int,expectedNumberOfAttributes: Int,recordLength:Int,attributes: Seq[Attributes])
    case class Attributes(attributeIdentifier: Int,attributeName:String,attributeMaximumLength:Int,datatype: Seq[DataType])
    case class DataType(datatypeName:String)

      object Json_Parser_Jackson  {
        def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
          val fileContent =  Source.fromFile("C:\\Users\\xxxnd\\ideaProject\\jsonparser\\src\\main\\resources\\Json_file.json","UTF-8").getLines.mkString

          val mapper = new ObjectMapper()
          mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)

          val person2: Definition = new ObjectMapper().readValue(fileContent,classOf[Definition])

          println(person2)


        }
      }
```

Json File

```
{
  "recordDefinitions": [
    {
      "recordDefinitionIdentifier": 2,
      "recordTypeCode": "LT",
      "recordTypePattern": "^.{14}LT.*$",
      "minimumNumberOfAttributes": 19,
      "expectedNumberOfAttributes": 19,
      "recordLength": 117,
      "attributes": [
        {
          "attributeIdentifier": 1,
          "attributeName": "PROVIDER TYPE",
          "attributeMaximumLength": 1,
          "datatype": {
            "datatypeName": "AN"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I am not mistaking, Scala case class does not have a parameterless constructor, but a constructor with all fields as parameters and an `apply` method of the companion object. Jackson object mapper, however requires a parameterless constructor to instantiate the class first. So the most "jackson" way would be to create a Java POJO instead of a case class like here: [Jackson Github](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind)

I would suggest you to use something like this:
[Implicit JSON conversion](http://lollyrock.com/articles/scala-implicit-conversion/)

Also see [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14442630/1205066)

Comment: Either no-parameters one, or use of `@JsonCreator` to indicate parameters-taking constructor to use (along with names for properties using `@JsonProperty`, or, Java 8 JVM and `jackson-module-parameter-names`)

Answer (score 0):

To spell out a concrete solution and save some of you time, this is the best way I have found:

```
case class MyData(@JsonProperty("myStringVar") myStringVar: String,
                  @JsonProperty("my_renamed_var") myRenamedVar: Int)
```

NB. Below Jackson 3.x[0], you will need to repeat the variable name in the annotation even if you don't rename it. In that case, you can consider including the [jackson-modules-java8](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8) you should be able to simply add a `@JsonProperty` annotation.

You can also add an empty constructor and [`@BeanProperty`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.7/scala/beans/BeanProperty.html) annotations, if you prefer a pure Scala approach.

[0] Such as version 2.6.7.1 of jackson-databind currently required by the AWS Lambda Java SDK.