# Scala string - json

Tags: json, scala

I'm new to Scala. I have a string as below

```
2017-07-07|{"success":true,"data":{"status":"200","message":"Operation completed."}}
```

I only need the second part of the string. I'm able to using map and split it into string as below

```
{"success":true,"data":{"status":"200","message":"Operation completed."}}
```

but it's suppose to be JSON, and I'm not able to parse it. Hope someone can give me some guide.

Comment: This is valid JSON. How do you parse it and what is the error ?

Comment: Which [JSON library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8054018/what-json-library-to-use-in-scala) are you using?

Answer (score 0):

```
val y = "2017-07-07|{\"success\":true,\"data\":{\"status\":\"200\",\"message\":\"Operation completed.\"}}"
val res = y.split('|')(1)
```

as for JSON serialization you can use **[lift_json](https://github.com/lift/lift/tree/master/framework/lift-base/lift-json/)** as it can be used independent, 
just add the dependency to your SBT file and then use the following code to parse the string

```
import net.liftweb.json._
parse(res)
```