# How can I convert any nested combination of maps, seqs, and basic types to JSON in Scala?

Tags: json, scala

In Python I can arbitrarily nest lists and dictionaries and use a mixture of types and then simply call `json.dumps(x)` and get the result I need.

I can't find anything like this in Scala. All the libraries I come across seem to insist on static typing and compile-time checks. I would rather give that up for simplicity. It seems that it should be possible to dynamically check the types of the inputs.

As a simple example, I would like to be able to do something like:

```
toJson(Map("count" -> 1,
           "objects" -> Seq(Map("bool_val" -> true,
                                "string_val" -> "hello"))))
```

which would output a string containing:

```
{"count": 1, "objects": [{"bool_val": true, "string_val": "hello"}]}
```

---

EDIT: Here is what happens when I try a couple of libraries:

```
scala> import upickle.default._
import upickle.default._

scala> write(Seq(1, 2))
res0: String = [1,2]

scala> write(Seq(1, "2"))
<console>:15: error: Couldn't derive type Seq[Any]
       write(Seq(1, "2"))
            ^

scala> import spray.json._
import spray.json._

scala> import spray.json.DefaultJsonProtocol._
import spray.json.DefaultJsonProtocol._

scala> Seq(1, 2).toJson
res2: spray.json.JsValue = [1,2]

scala> Seq(1, "2").toJson
<console>:21: error: Cannot find JsonWriter or JsonFormat type class for Seq[Any]
       Seq(1, "2").toJson
                   ^
```

I tried creating my own general protocol for spray but I'm getting weird results:

```
import spray.json._

object MyJsonProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol {

  implicit object AnyJsonWriter extends JsonFormat[Any] {
    def write(x: Any) = x match {
      case n: Int => JsNumber(n)
      case n: Long => JsNumber(n)
      case d: Double => JsNumber(d)
      case s: String => JsString(s)
      case b: Boolean if b => JsTrue
      case b: Boolean if !b => JsFalse
      case m: Map[Any, Any] => m.toJson
      case p: Product => p.productIterator.toList.toJson  // for tuples
      case s: Seq[Any] => s.toJson
      case a: Array[Any] => a.toJson
    }

    override def read(json: JsValue) = ???
  }

}

import MyJsonProtocol._

val objects = Seq(Map(
  "bool_val" -> true,
  "string_val" -> "hello"))

objects.toJson.toString
// [{"bool_val":true,"string_val":"hello"}]

Map(
  "count" -> 1,
  "objects" -> objects).toJson.toString
// {"count":1,"objects":[{"bool_val":true,"string_val":"hello"},[]]}
//                          I don't know where this comes from: ^
```

Comment: Maybe this answer will provide some info https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8054018/what-json-library-to-use-in-scala. But there are too many libraries.

Comment: Scala is all about strict typing and compile-time safety. If you want to give that up "for simplicity", why not just write in python to begin with?

Comment: But, yeah, you can do what you are describing in scala, it's possible, just not very useful. I am not sure what you are asking exactly.

Comment: @Dima Among other things, I have a `List[Map[String, Any]]` from a spark dataframe whose schema is determined by user input, so I can't do much proper typing.

Comment: So, what's the question? Whatever library you use to generate json should be able to deal with that type.

Comment: If the schema is determined by user input, then you should ask for some sort of `JsonEncoder`/`JsonDecoder` for the user-defined types. That is how most libraries that allow this kind of stuff work.

Comment: @Dima no, `Any` freaks libraries out, that's why I'm here. `Seq(1, "2")` is enough of a problem.

Comment: @HTNW no, that's not the kind of user I mean. Point is, this isn't an XY problem, please let that go.

Comment: @AlexHall You gotta be (_a lot_) more specific with that: what libraries are you using, what do you mean by "freaks out" etc.?
Have you read about mcve? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Dima I've added some examples.

Comment: I don't know spray ... what you are describing looks like a bug. I recommend jackson with scala module. Perhaps, you'll have better luck with that. Judging from your sample, it would also require A LOT less boilerplate to set up.

Comment: @Dima thanks for the pointer, I managed to do it with Jackson (see answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on https://coderwall.com/p/o--apg/easy-json-un-marshalling-in-scala-with-jackson:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.experimental.ScalaObjectMapper

val mapper = new ObjectMapper() with ScalaObjectMapper
mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)

def toJson(value: Any): String = {
  mapper.writeValueAsString(value)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to throw away the type system and cast everything:

```
import math._ // For BigDecimal and the associated implicit conversions

// Dispatch to another overload if possible, or crash and burn with MatchError
def toJson(any: Any): String = any match {
  case null            => "null"
  case obj: Map[_, _]  => toJson(obj.asInstanceOf[Map[String, Any]])
  case arr: Seq[_]     => toJson(arr)
  case str: String     => toJson(str)
  case  bl: Boolean    => toJson(bl)
  case  bd: BigDecimal => toJson(bd)
  // v Convert to BD so toJson(Number) doesn't need to be duplicated
  case   l: Long       => toJson(l: BigDecimal)
  case   i: Int        => toJson(i: BigDecimal)
  case   s: Short      => toJson(s: BigDecimal)
  case   c: Char       => toJson(c: BigDecimal)
  case   b: Byte       => toJson(b: BigDecimal)
  case   f: Float      => toJson(f: BigDecimal)
  case   d: Double     => toJson(d: BigDecimal)
}

def toJson(obj: Map[String, Any]): String =
  // Build a list of "key": "value" entries
  obj.foldRight(Seq.empty[String]) { case ((prop, value), building) =>
    s"${toJson(prop)}: ${toJson(value)}" +: building
  }.mkString("{ ", ", ", " }")
  // Wrap in { ... } and add ", "s

def toJson(arr: Seq[Any]): String =
  // Build list of JSON strings
  arr.foldRight(Seq.empty[String]) { (value, building) =>
    toJson(value) +: building
  }.mkString("[ ", ", ", " ]")
  // Wrap in [ ... ] and add ", "s

// Process each character, one by one
def toJson(str: String): String = str.flatMap {
  // Common escapes
  case '\\' => "\\\\"
  case '"'  => "\\\""
  case '\b' => "\\b"
  case '\f' => "\\f"
  case '\n' => "\\n"
  case '\r' => "\\r"
  case '\t' => "\\t"
  // All the other control characters
  case ctrl if ctrl < ' ' => f"\\u${ctrl}%04x"
  // Nothing special: leave unchanged
  case c  => c.toString
}.mkString("\"", "", "\"")
// Wrap in "..."

def toJson(bl: Boolean): String = bl.toString

def toJson(bd: BigDecimal): String = bd.toString
```

Please note that this is a very un-Scala thing to do. Python doesn't have a type system like Scala, and that's why you are used to runtime-checked code like this. But Scala isn't like that, and you should be working *with* the typer, not against it. For one, creating maps and seqs containing `Any` like this is a massive red flag. Consider using `case class`es to hold data. To that purpose, a lot of the JSON libraries for Scala support auto-deriving JSON en-/de-coders, usually with [`shapeless.Generic`](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#generic-representation-of-sealed-families-of-case-classes).

Comment: This is impressive, I wasn't expecting a solution from scratch, but I don't feel great using it. I'd prefer to use a well established and tested library so that I know that all corner cases in the spec are handled. It also doesn't look very fast (e.g. `str.flatMap`).