# How to remove key value from json var using scala

Tags: scala

I have the following String var input:

```
val json= """[{"first": 1, "name": "abc", "timestamp": "2018/06/28"},
             {"first": 2, "name": "mtm", "timestamp": "2018/06/28"}]"""
```

I need to remove key value(timestamp)

expected output:

```
val result= "[{"first": 1, "name": "abc"},{"first": 2, "name": "mtm"}]"
```

please kindly help.

Comment: can you add more, what you tried?

Comment: Are you parsing the JSON in any way or is it exclusively a String?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple regex will do it:

```
json.replaceAll(""",\s*"timestamp"[^,}]*""", "")
```

Comment: do JSONs preserve order? e.g. what if timestamp is the first key (where the first comma will be missing), as it may be in the future?

Comment: @JoelBerkeley Yes, this is a specific answer to this situation. It won't work if "timestamp" is the first key, or if there are `,` or `}` characters embedded in the value. Better to use a JSON library in the general case

Answer (score 1):

Or with a JSON parser, (though it's quite hard to answer w/o knowing what JSON parser you're using), perhaps

- parse it, with one of these [What JSON library to use in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8054018/what-json-library-to-use-in-scala)
- then remove the "timestamp" entries with e.g. `List.map(m => m - "timestamp")` (depends on which library you're using)
- recompile the JSON