# How to iterate through json array in scala

Tags: arrays, json, scala, scala-collections

I have a json array like below which is fetched from a database column into scala

`jsonArrayString = "[{"firstName": "Harry", "lastName": "Smith"}, {"firstName": "John", "lastName": "Ken"}]"`

I want to iterate through this array and get the values of dictionary keys in a for loop.

Thanks much for your help!

Comment: Define a case class like `final case class User(firstName: String, lastName: String)` and use any of the plenty **Json** libraries to parse that string tino a `List[User]` then you can process that list using `map`, `foreach`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scala doesn't have any built-in JSON processing, so you'll need to use a third-party library.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14442630/3277618) lists Scala-specific libraries and any Java library would also work.

Even though it's not Scala-specific I usually use [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson), when I'm working with JSON in Scala because it's usually already on the classpath in the apps I work in and it's a safe bet it will be supported well into the future because it's so widely used.  It has an [optional Scala module](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-scala) that adapts it to play well with Scala's built in types.

Here's one way to parse `jsonArrayString` if Jackson and its Scala module are on your classpath:

```scala
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala._

case class Person(firstName : String, lastName : String)

val jackson = new ObjectMapper with ScalaObjectMapper
jackson.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)

val jsonArrayString =
  """[{"firstName": "Harry", "lastName": "Smith"},
     |{"firstName": "John",  "lastName": "Ken"}]""".stripMargin

jackson.readValue[List[Person]](jsonArrayString).foreach { person =>
  println(s"First Name: ${person.firstName}; Last Name: ${person.lastName}")
}
```

If either `firstName` or `lastName` could be null or absent, you can declare them with type `Option[String]` and the Scala module will map `null` to `None`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I was able to successfully parse it and iterate.

Answer (score 1):

This question is very broad. There are numerous JSON parsing libraries in Scala, which make this a trivial task.
They will all deserialize a JSON array to a scala list of whatever type you decode it to.
Since you are dealing with a product, you can choose to use any Product type such as a builtin Tuple or a custom class.
Personally I am partial to Circe https://github.com/circe/circe

Answer (score 0):

```
libraryDependencies += "org.json" % "json" % "20200518"
```

This is helpful for Json iteration.