# XML to JSON with Scala

Tags: scala

For a XML snippet like this:

```
val fruits =
<fruits>
  <fruit>
    <name>apple</name>
    <taste>ok</taste>
  </fruit>
  <fruit>
    <name>banana</name>
    <taste>better</taste>
  </fruit>
</fruits>
```

doing something like:

```
fruits \\ "fruit"
```

will return a sequence of type `scala.xml.NodeSeq` with all the fruits and sub nodes inside.

What is the best way to convert this to a list of JSON objects? I'm trying to send my list of fruits back to a browser. I had a look at `scala.util.parsing.json.JSONObject` and `scala.util.parsing.json.JSONArray`, but I don't know how to get from NodeSeq to anyone of the latter.

If at all possible, I would love to see how it's done with plain Scala code.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9406592/947542) might be relevant. Here is my solution using [spray-json](https://github.com/spray/spray-json):

```
import scala.xml._
import cc.spray.json._
import cc.spray.json.DefaultJsonProtocol._

implicit object NodeFormat extends JsonFormat[Node] {
  def write(node: Node) =
    if (node.child.count(_.isInstanceOf[Text]) == 1)
      JsString(node.text)
    else
      JsObject(node.child.collect {
        case e: Elem => e.label -> write(e)
      }: _*)

  def read(jsValue: JsValue) = null // not implemented
}

val fruits =
  <fruits>
    <fruit>
      <name>apple</name>
      <taste>
        <sweet>true</sweet>
        <juicy>true</juicy>
      </taste>
    </fruit>
    <fruit>
      <name>banana</name>
      <taste>better</taste>
    </fruit>
  </fruits>

val json = """[{"name":"apple","taste":{"sweet":"true","juicy":"true"}},{"name":"banana","taste":"better"}]"""

assert((fruits \\ "fruit").toSeq.toJson.toString == json)
```

Comment: This looks great, but your sample does not run. I get the following: error: not found: value JsField.

Comment: @JacobusR Oops, still using 1.0.1 version of spray-json. There is indeed no `JsField` class in 1.1.0. Replaced it with a tuple.

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks. Always lovely to get a runnable bit of code, rather than just a snippet (+1 for that :-).

Comment: FYI SprayJson has been recently updated, looks like `JsonFormat` has moved

Comment: A `JsonWriter` is more appropriate here as it means you don't need to have a dangling unimplemented `read`.

Comment: This is pretty cool. The only thing I can think that would be cool to add would be to convert any attributes on the xml nodes to become properties for an object, so rather than `{name:banana}` you'd end up with `{name: banana, attrX:attrVal}`

Comment: what about attributes?

Answer (score 3):

org.json4s makes this pretty simple:

```
import org.json4s.Xml.toJson

val fruits =
  <fruits>
    <fruit>
      <name>apple</name>
      <taste>
        <sweet>true</sweet>
        <juicy>true</juicy>
      </taste>
    </fruit>
    <fruit>
      <name>banana</name>
      <taste>better</taste>
    </fruit>
  </fruits>

println(toJson(fruits))
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use [ScalaXB](http://scalaxb.org/) to turn the XML into scala classes and then write the appropriate toJson bits to output Json.

Should work a treat.

Comment: The problem with ScalaXB is that it requires XML schema