# How to convert Option[scala.xml.Elem] values into String

Tags: xml, string, scala, playframework, playframework-2.3

I am newbie to `Play Framework(Scala)`in my project I need to convert `XML` response values as a normal `String`

**What I actually need**

```
val result:Option[Elem] = //response from web server
```

for eg consider this XML values as `result` variable value

```
<response><play>Scala</play><version>2.3.9</version></response>
```

I need to get the XML values as String like this below

```
println("resultString:="+resultString)
```

needed output

```
resultString:=<response><play>Scala</play><version>2.3.9</version><response>
```

I check with these below two methods but it didn't convert the whole `XML` values into `String` like what I need.It gave only the values like `Scala2.3.9` not like XML String.

```
val resultString:String = result.get.text
val resultString:String = result.get.toString()
```

**Edited**

while print the `result.get.toString()` it prints the `XML` values as `String` but what I am doing in my project is I am setting the `String` value into some `JsObject` like this `Json.obj("resultString"->result.get.toString())`. when I get the `JsObject` from response,it is just showing the values only,not showing the `Tags`

Comment: did you try `result.get.mkString`?

Comment: The tag `<response>` is not closed properly with `</response>`. Other wise `result.get.toString` will work.

Comment: @johny actually I get some `xml` values here I posted `dummy` values.all tags in original response has been closed properly.

Comment: To be sure I just tried again in REPL and `toString` works fine for me.

Comment: @johny I check with `result.get.toString()` it is returning the same value what I have mentioned in my question.

Comment: @Zoltán I check with `result.get.mkString` it also returning the same.

Comment: @johny  while print the `result.get.toString()` it prints the `XML` values as `String` but what I am doing in my project is I am setting the `String` value into some `JsObject` like this `Json.obj("resultString"->result.get.toString())`. when I get the `JsValue` from response,it is just showing the values only,not showing the `Tags`

Comment: @Manoj what does this print: `println(Json.obj("resultString"->result.get.toString()))`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9516973/xml-to-json-with-scala this should be helpful for you

Comment: @Jus12 `println(Json.obj("resultString"->result.get.toString()))` prints the XML String values

Comment: @Manoj can you paste the actual output. Not very clear what you mean by XML String values.

Comment: `{"resultString":"<response><play>Scala</play><version>2.3.9</version></response>"}`

Answer (score 2):

By default, Scala has the behavior you desire. See the below output:

```
scala> val resultString = <response><play>Scala</play><version>2.3.9</version></response>
resultString: scala.xml.Elem = <response><play>Scala</play><version>2.3.9</version></response>

scala> println("resultString:="+resultString)
resultString:=<response><play>Scala</play><version>2.3.9</version></response>
```

This should convert to string:

```
scala> resultString.toString
res1: String = <response><play>Scala</play><version>2.3.9</version></response>
```