# Scala : How to convert xml Elem, with mixed tags, to JSON string?

Tags: json, xml, scala

I want to convert below XML object,

```
val xml = <body>
    <para>first</para>
    <para>second</para>
    <sometag>xyz</sometag>
</body>
```

to JSON

```
{"body":{"para":["first","second"],"sometag":"xyz"}}
```

I've tried below scala libraries,

**1. net.liftweb | lift-json_2.11 | 3.3.0**

```
import net.liftweb._

import net.liftweb.json.Xml.XmlNode

import net.liftweb.json.Xml

import net.liftweb.json._


println("JSON STRING" + compactRender(toJson(xml)))
```

output: {"body":{"para":"first","para":"second","sometag":"xyz"}}

**2. org.json4s | json4s-xml_2.11 | 3.6.5**

```
import org.json4s.Xml.{ toJson, toXml }

import org.json4s._

import org.json4s.JsonDSL._

import org.json4s.native.JsonMethods.{ render, pretty, compact }


println("JSON String:" + compact(render(toJSON(xml))))
```

output: {"body":{"para":"first","para":"second","sometag":"xyz"}}

in both the cases, I see duplicate keys (note that para is seen twice) which is invalid in JSON. Rather, my expectation is, if a duplicate XML tag is seen in XML document, the convertor must places those values in array as shown below

```
{"body":{"para":["first","second"],"sometag":"xyz"}}
```

Comment: Probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9516973/xml-to-json-with-scala

Comment: There's a vast number of different libraries for converting XML to JSON; they all do it differently, and none of them gets it right every time. To get your conversion "right", the library somehow has to know that the order of the two para elements is significant, but the relative order of the sometag child isn't. How can it be expected to know that?

Comment: What would you want `<body><para><inner>first</inner></para><para>second</para><sometag>xyz</sometag></body>` to print?

Comment: @james-whiteley 
<body><para><inner>first</inner></para><para>second</para><sometag>xyz</sometag></body> should print to  { "body":{ "para": [{"inner":"first}, "second" ], "sometag":"xyz" } }

Comment: Btw, It actually does parse into a list if there are *only* "para" tags in the enclosing tag, so if you didn't have the `sometag` or added a parent to the "para" it works. As mentioned here, there are many ways to parse such a list..

Answer (score 1):

(it's a little late.) 
you can use *org.json* Java library for this.

```
import org.json.XML

val xml = """<body>
    <para>first</para>
    <para>second</para>
    <sometag>xyz</sometag>
</body>"""

val jsonStr = XML.toJSONObject(xmlData).toString( indentFactor=4 )

println(jsonStr)

Output:

{"body": {

    "para": [
        "first",
        "second"
    ],
    "sometag": "xyz"
}}
```

Note: The order of the JSON elements may vary.