# How to convert json file to List using scala

Tags: scala

I have the following json input
sample.json

```
[{"level": 1, "firstFile": "one", "secondFile": "first"},
 {"level": 1, "firstFile": "two", "secondFile": "sec"},
 {"level": 2, "firstFile": "three", "secondFile": "third"}]
```

i want my result should be:

```
val first= List(List("one","two"),List("three"))
val second= List(List("first","sec"),List("third"))
```

build.sbt:

```
name := "Test"
version := "1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.11.0"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq("org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.11" % "2.0.0" % "provided")
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.2.0"
libraryDependencies ++= Seq("org.slf4j" % "slf4j-api" % "1.7.5",
                            "org.clapper" %% "grizzled-slf4j" % "1.3.1")
libraryDependencies += "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-core" % "1.2.3"
libraryDependencies += "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.2.3" % "test"
libraryDependencies += "com.databricks" % "spark-avro_2.11" % "4.0.0"
libraryDependencies += "io.circe" %% "circe-config" % "0.4.1"               
retrieveManaged := true
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually you convert JSON to case classes using a library like Jackson or Circe.

```
val json = """[{"level": 1, "firstFile": "one", "secondFile": "first"},
             | {"level": 1, "firstFile": "one", "secondFile": "first"},
             | {"level": 2, "firstFile": "two", "secondFile": "sec"},
             | {"level": 2, "firstFile": "two", "secondFile": "sec"}]""".stripMargin

case class My2FileThing(level: Int, firstFile: String, secondFile: String)

val parsed: List[My2FileThing] = {
  // TODO parse json using some library; there are many available

  List(
    My2FileThing(1, "one", "first"),
    My2FileThing(1, "one", "first"),
    My2FileThing(2, "two", "sec"),
    My2FileThing(2, "two", "sec")
  )
}
```

The json you provided is a one dimensional `List` containing four of these items, as above.

To transform that data into the two Lists you asked for, you can do this, I guess. You have not told us the logic behind your transformation.

```
val firstLineChandraWants: List[List[String]] =
  parsed.map(_.firstFile).groupBy(identity).values.toList
val secondLineChandraWants: List[List[String]] =
  parsed.map(_.secondFile).groupBy(identity).values.toList
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. could you please help me how to parse the JSON.

Comment: There are a lot of libraries available that will do this. See the link in @Ravinder's answer. Usually if you are needing to parse Json, you are writing a web server, and using a web framework, and most web frameworks include some kind of Json parser that you might as well use rather than importing something else.

Comment: It looks like you have imported the Circe library which is a good popular one - you can learn how to use it here; https://circe.github.io/circe/parsing.html

Answer (score 0):

Use some library for converting the Json String to a Scala object/type.

For more info: [How to convert JSON to a type in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11889907/how-to-convert-json-to-a-type-in-scala)

Example using Lift:

```
import net.liftweb.json._
implicit val formats = DefaultFormats // Brings in default date formats etc.
val json = """
[{"level": 1, "firstFile": "one", "secondFile": "first"},
 {"level": 1, "firstFile": "two", "secondFile": "sec"},
 {"level": 2, "firstFile": "three", "secondFile": "third"}]
"""
case class ListSubType(level: Int, firstFile: String, secondFile: String)

val parsed: List[ListSubType] =  parse(json).extract[List[ListSubType]]
val desired: List[List[String]] = parsed.map(a => List(a.firstFile, a.secondFile))

// will produce: List(List("one", "first"), List("two", "sec"), List("three", "third"))
```

I know you asked different elements(of root list) in different variables, but it's better to use index or iterate over list than using different variables. Practically length of list is indefinite, so how are you gonna assign different items to different variables.
Example=>

```
/**
* Using index
*/
val first:Option[String] = desired.get(0) // will return Option[String]
val second:Option[String] = desired.get(1) // will return Option[String]

for (items <- desired) {
   println(items)
}
```

Use this link to get import code for your desired build tool/package manger.

https://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Cnet.liftweb%7Clift-json%7C2.0%7Cjar

Comment: I am getting error at import net.liftweb.json._  object liftweb is not a member of package net

Comment: @ Ravinder Payal thanks for the reply. I added libraryDependencies += "net.liftweb" %% "lift-json" % "2.4-M5" but while running the sbt i am getting error.  [error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: net.liftweb#lift-json_2.11;2.4-M5: not found
[error] Could not create Eclipse project files:
[error] [Error evaluating task 'scalacOptions': error,Error evaluating task 'externalDependencyClasspath': error,Error evaluating task 'update': error,Error evaluating task 'updateClassifiers': error,Error evaluating task 'updateClassifiers': error]. Any other help?

Comment: @Chandra Share your sbt file as a question edit, it seems you haven't mapped any central repository in your build.sbt

Comment: added the buid.sbt file. please suggest.